# \dag doubles index entries - how to avoid?

Tags: symbols, footnotes, indexing

Using the symbol `\dag` within a `splitindex` command, in the index output two entries are produced: One naming the pages where the `\sindex` command is used in the text, another where it is used in the footnotes. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Example:

```
Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)} and Peter died
recently.\footnote{Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)} died earlier}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of a complete compilable `.tex` file, so I can paste it into my editor and reproduce your situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way indexing programs need to read your `.tex` file is very tricky.  This is what leads to problems.  In the code you have used, if you examine the resulting `.idx` file, you will see this:

```
\indexentry[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)}{1}
\indexentry[p]{Paul (\dag  1999)}{1}
```

And `makeindex` (or `splitindex`) will treat them differently.  You can work around this by having this in your input instead:

```
Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)} and Peter died
recently.\footnote{Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\string\dag\space 1999)} died earlier}
```

This will yield:---

```
\indexentry[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)}{1}
\indexentry[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)}{1}
```

---and will, after running (in your case) `splitindex`, give you only one index entry (to page 1).

As an aside, you may find that inserting a thin space between your two elements, viz `\dag\,1999`, looks better.

A minimal example is almost always helpful to everyone, so here's a complete file for testing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[Index]{p}

\begin{document}

Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)} and Peter died
% recently.\footnote{Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\dag 1999)} died earlier}
recently.\footnote{Paul\sindex[p]{Paul (\string\dag\space 1999)} died earlier}


\printindex*
\end{document}
```